# Who is cold enough to edit out a compliment?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question

The meta community is against small talk in questions (not the programming language) and is [in favor of editing them out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/3021#3021).  So, who wants to be cold enough to edit out the compliment in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449213/multiple-repeat-replace-on-one-page)?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Downvoter, I didn't think there had to be a question on meta, hence the discussion tag.  But, to get to the gist of it, I wanted to know if anyone would edit out someone saying such nice things about the community, and take the opportunity to recognize the community for such good work.

Comment: The answer is: there's probably someone who would.

Comment: I more against the language then the practice. It's always showing off its reflection, thinking it's so much more clever then the rest of us.

Comment: Could someone please be so cold as to edit out the last line of this post. I don't have the rep.

Comment: If only you could vote on revisions @shog

Answer (score 5):

I cleaned up the question and edited out the irrelevant bits. Let me know if you think I lost any of the author's original intent.

Comment: It looks vastly improved.

Answer (score 1):

I think the idea was to eliminate the "auto-sig" stuff some people use in e-mails.

Whenever there's such a big community, you can't completely eliminate the pleasantries that make things go smoothly for everyone. To keep the noise down, they shouldn't be encouraged; but at the same time, actively discouraging them probably isn't a wise move either.

From what I've seen, this type of thing is actually pretty rare, and I'd just as well let it go. It doesn't add value to the question content, but it adds value to the site (meta-value, I guess).

The "hi/thanks" stuff is more noisy, as it doesn't add any value to the site content at all.

Answer (score 0):

Done.

Comment: Thanks to the OP for bringing it to our attention